# Ionic obtiene los contactos muy lento

Tags: android, nodejs, ios, ionic, cordova

Al obtener los contactos por medio del plugin de cordova-plugin-contacts. Cuando corro el script para obtener alrededor de 300 contactos es muy demorado, dura 8 segundos aproximadamente, ¿alguien conoce una solución?

Ionic Info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.9.4
npm        : 6.0.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Función para obtener mensajes:

```
getAllContactsFromPhoneBook() {
    return new Promise((resolve => {
      this.contacts.find(['id', 'name', 'phoneNumbers'], {multiple: true, hasPhoneNumber:true})
        .then((data: any) => {
          for (let i of data) {
            if (i.name.formatted) {
              if (i.phoneNumbers) {
                let name = i.name.formatted;
                this.contactsNames.push(
                  name
                );
                let id = i.id;
                let phone = i.phoneNumbers;
                this.contactsArray.push({
                  id: id,
                  name: name,
                  phone: phone
                });
              }
            }
          }
          this.contactsOrder = this.contactsNames;
          this.groupContacts(this.contactsOrder, this.groupedContacts).then(() => {
            this.groupedAllContacts = this.groupedContacts;
          });
          resolve(true);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          resolve(false);
        });
    }));
}
```

Comment: Como nota: parece que [ese plugin está considerado obsoleto](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/#deprecation-notice) y ya no cuenta con soporte de la comunidad de Cordova (seguirá funcionando como estaba, pero si contiene errores no se arreglarán).

Comment: ¿Has probado lo que se sugiere en [este hilo](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/slow-synchronized-loading-of-contacts-in-ngcordova/16115/10)? (en concreto lo que sugieren jayber y rodrigo_am2)

Comment: Voy a probarlo, gracias